# How to filter out specific strings from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, praw

Python beginner here. I'm stumped on part of this code for a bot I'm writing.

I am making a reddit bot using Praw to comb through posts and removed a specific set of characters (steam CD keys).

I made a test post here: https://www.reddit.com/r/pythonforengineers/comments/91m4l0/testing_my_reddit_scraping_bot/

This should have all the formats of keys.

Currently, my bot is able to find the post using a regex expression. I have these variables:

```
steamKey15 = (r'\w\w\w\w\w.\w\w\w\w\w.\w\w\w\w\w')
steamKey25 = (r'\w\w\w\w\w.\w\w\w\w\w.\w\w\w\w\w.\w\w\w\w\w.\w\w\w\w\w.')
steamKey17 = (r'\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\s\w\w')
```

I am finding the text using this:

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('pythonforengineers')
for submission in subreddit.new(limit=20):

    if submission.id not in steamKeyPostID:        
        if re.search(steamKey15, submission.selftext, re.IGNORECASE):
            searchLogic()
            saveSteamKey()
```

So this is just to show that the things I should be using in a filter function is a combination of steamKey15/25/17, and submission.selftext.

So here is the part where I am confused. I cant find a function that works, or is doing what I want. My goal is to remove all the text from submission.selftext(the body of the post) BUT the keys, which will eventually be saved in a .txt file.

Any advice on a good way to go around this? I've looked into re.sub and .translate but I don't understand how the parts fit together.

I am using Python 3.7 if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you just get the regexp results?

```
m = re.search(steamKey15, submission.selftext, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print(m.group(0))
```

Also note that a dot `.` means **any char** in a regexp. If you want to match only dots, you should use `\.`. You can probably write your regexp like this instead:

```
r'\w{5}[-.]\w{5}[-.]\w{5}'
```

This will match the key when separated by `.` or by `-`.

Note that this will also match anything that begin or end with a key, or has a key in the middle - that can cause you problems as your 15-char key regexp is contained in the 25-key one! To fix that use negative lookahead/negative lookbehind:

```
r'(?<![\w.-])\w{5}[-.]\w{5}[-.]\w{5}(?![\w.-])'
```

that will only find the keys if there are no extraneous characters before and after them

Another hint is to use `re.findall` instead of `re.search` - some posts contain more than one steam key in the same post! `findall` will return all matches while `search` only returns the first one.

Comment: Hey thanks! Lots of great things that I didn't know here! I tried implementing your code but am running into an error with the group line:    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @Synik if you use `.findall` then you don't have to use `.group` at all: `for key in re.findall(steamKey15, submission.selftext, flags=re.IGNORECASE): saveSteamKey(key)`  because  `findall` returns a list of matches already in string format

Comment: Awesome, I removed the group and just did a print(m) and it returns just the 1 15 key, and also 15 characters of the 25 key (I am only running it with the 15 key statement for testing). Will this return duplicates when I implement the 25/17?

Comment: you can add word boundaries to the regexp to prevent it from finding keys with extra characters: `r'\b\w{5}[-.]\w{5}[-.]\w{5}'\b` @Synik

Comment: typo:  `r'\b\w{5}[-.]\w{5}[-.]\w{5}\b'`

Comment: Logically that makes sense, but its still returning 15 characters of the next string. I copied/pasted the typo corrected one to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: @Synik it seems that dots and `-` are considered non-words! We have to use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind. try this: `r'(?<![\w.-])\w{5}[-.]\w{5}[-.]\w{5}(?![\w.-])'` - I added this info to the answer

Comment: wow as someone who learned regex a few hours ago, that can get pretty crazy looking! It works great though! Marked as answer, perfectly solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So a couple things first `.` means any character in regex. I think you know that, but just to be sure. Also `\w\w\w\w\w` can be replaced with `\w{5}` where this specifies 5 alphanumerics. I would use `re.findall`.

```
import re
steamKey15 = (r'(?:\w{5}.){2}\w{5}')
steamKey25 = (r'(?:\w{5}.){5}')
steamKey17 = (r'\w{15}\s\w\w')
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('pythonforengineers')
for submission in subreddit.new(limit=20):
    if submission.id not in steamKeyPostID:
        finds_15 = re.findall(steamKey15, submission.selftext)
        finds_25 = re.findall(steamKey25, submission.selftext)
        finds_17 = re.findall(steamKey17, submission.selftext)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm also new to this, but findall returns a list, so you can just loop through those to find the steamKeys that your code picks up. :)

Comment: Thanks for the great tips! I've changed my regex around to be less repetitive. This seems to be the closest I have gotten so far. My only question is what is causing the code to return 20 lines of brackets with the mock key on line 9?

Comment: I don't know how the reddit portion of your code works, but if there were no matches for the steamKey25 then the corresponding finds_25 will become an empty list. Since it looks like you only pick the first 20 submissions, maybe there were no matches in any of those submissions?